# button collector inside button collector discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, blackjack

So I'm trying to code a Blackjack command for my Discord bot, and the **aces** in Blackjack can have 2 values: `1` or `11` based on player's choice.
I'm trying to make that the player can choose to **call** or **stay**, with button interactions, and that works, for now. The thing is that when the random card is equal to 1, I want to change the labels of the buttons and create another collector to collect the `1` or `11` choice, making the code wait with an `await`. here's the collector:

```
const filter = (btnInt) => { return interaction.user.id === btnInt.user.id }
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 60000 });
        const aceCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, max: 1, time: 30000});

        collector.on("collect", async (btnInt) => {

            await btnInt.deferUpdate();


            switch (btnInt.customId) {

                case "call":
                    randomCard();

                    if (randCard == 1) {

                        matchEmbed.description = `You pulled an ace! Select the value of it: ${codeLine("1")} or ${codeLine("11")}?
                        \n\n ** The sum of your cards (without the ace is) is: ** ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}`;

                        btnInt.editReply({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [aceRow] });

                        aceCollector.on("collect", async (aceInt) => {

                            await aceInt.deferUpdate();

                            console.log(aceCollector)

                            if (aceInt.customId == "1") randCard = 1;

                            else randCard = 11;

                            playerCards.push(randCard);
                        });

                        aceCollector.on("end", () => {

                            matchEmbed.description = `**you pulled ${codeLine(randCard)} from the deck!
                            \n ${interaction.user.username}'s cards** \n${codeLine(playerCards.join(" | "))} | sum: ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}
                            \n\n **Dealer's cards **${codeLine(dealerCard1)} | ${codeLine(dealerCard2)} | sum: ${codeLine(sum)}
                            \n\n ** Do you want to call another card or do you wanna stay? **`;

                            interaction.editReply({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [aceRow]});
                        });
                    }

                    else {

                        matchEmbed.description = `**you pulled ${codeLine(randCard)} from the deck!
                        \n${interaction.user.username}'s cards** \n${codeLine(playerCards.join(" | "))} | sum: ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}
                        \n\n **Dealer's cards **${codeLine(dealerCard1)} | ${codeLine(dealerCard2)} | sum: ${codeLine(sum)}
                        \n\n ** Do you want to call another card or do you wanna stay? **`; 
                    }

                    if (lodash.sum(playerCards) > 21) {

                        matchEmbed.description = `**${interaction.user.username}'s cards** \n${codeLine(playerCards.join(" | "))} | sum: ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}
                        \n **Busted! The sum your cards are over 21!**
                        \n\n **Dealer's cards **${codeLine(dealerCard1)} | ${codeLine(dealerCard2)} | sum: ${codeLine(sum)}
                        \n\n ** Wait for the Dealer... **`;

                        row.components[0].setDisabled(true);
                    }

                    if (lodash.sum(playerCards) == 21) {

                        matchEmbed.description = `**${interaction.user.username}'s cards** \n${codeLine(playerCards.join(" | "))} | sum: ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}
                        \n **Blackjack!**
                        \n\n **Dealer's cards **${codeLine(dealerCard1)} | ${codeLine(dealerCard2)} | sum: ${codeLine(sum)}
                        \n\n ** Wait for the Dealer... **`;

                        row.components[0].setDisabled(true);
                    }

                    break;

                case "stay":
                    matchEmbed.setDescription("stay");

                    break;
            }

            btnInt.editReply({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [row] });
        });

        function randomCard() {

            randCard = chance.pickone(cards);

            if (randCard !== 1) {

                cards.splice(cards.indexOf(randCard), 1);
                playerCards.push(randCard);
            }
        }
```

When the player gets a an ace, the code goes through the `if (randCard == 1)`, so the message in discord actually changes and even the buttons, but for some reason it instantly changes back to the normal message to call or stay. 
I tried to console log something, and it does not show up, so the collector does not even start, so it won't wait. How can I solve this? Here's the full code of the command:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
var lodash = require('lodash');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("blackjack")
    .setDescription("Play a blackjack game, I will be the dealer!")
    .addIntegerOption(option => 
        option.setName("bet")
        .setDescription("The amount of bananas you wanna bet.")),

    async execute(client, interaction, Discord, profileData) {

        let players = 1;
        let randCard;
        let rematch = false;

        const cards = chance.shuffle([
            1, 1, 1, 1,
            2, 2, 2, 2,
            3, 3, 3, 3,
            4, 4, 4, 4,
            5, 5, 5, 5,
            6, 6, 6, 6,
            7, 7, 7, 7,
            8, 8, 8, 8,
            9, 9, 9, 9,
            10, 10, 10, 10,
            10, 10, 10, 10,
            10, 10, 10, 10,
            10, 10, 10, 10,
        ]);

        const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("call").setLabel("Call").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
            new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("stay").setLabel("Stay").setStyle("SECONDARY")
        );

        const aceRow = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("1").setLabel("1").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
            new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("11").setLabel("11").setStyle("SECONDARY")
        );

        const playerCards = [
            chance.pickone(cards),
            chance.pickone(cards)
        ];

        let dealerCard1 = chance.pickone(cards);
        let dealerCard2 = "?";
        let sum = "?";

        const matchEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor({ name: `${interaction.user.username}`, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({format: "png"})})
        .setTitle("Blackjack")
        .setDescription(`**${interaction.user.username}'s cards** \n${codeLine(playerCards.join(" | "))} | sum: ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))} 
        \n\n **Dealer's cards **${codeLine(dealerCard1)} | ${codeLine(dealerCard2)} | sum: ${codeLine(sum)}
        \n\n ** Do you want to call another card or do you wanna stay? **`)
        .setColor("BLACK");

        interaction.reply({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [row]});

        const filter = (btnInt) => { return interaction.user.id === btnInt.user.id }
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 60000 });
        const aceCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, max: 1, time: 30000});

        collector.on("collect", async (btnInt) => {

            await btnInt.deferUpdate();


            switch (btnInt.customId) {

                case "call":
                    randomCard();

                    if (randCard == 1) {

                        matchEmbed.description = `You pulled an ace! Select the value of it: ${codeLine("1")} or ${codeLine("11")}?
                        \n\n ** The sum of your cards (without the ace is) is: ** ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}`;

                        btnInt.editReply({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [aceRow] });

                        await aceCollector.on("collect", async (aceInt) => {

                            await aceInt.deferUpdate();

                            console.log(aceCollector)

                            if (aceInt.customId == "1") randCard = 1;

                            else randCard = 11;

                            playerCards.push(randCard);
                        });

                        await aceCollector.on("end", () => {

                            matchEmbed.description = `**you pulled ${codeLine(randCard)} from the deck!
                            \n ${interaction.user.username}'s cards** \n${codeLine(playerCards.join(" | "))} | sum: ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}
                            \n\n **Dealer's cards **${codeLine(dealerCard1)} | ${codeLine(dealerCard2)} | sum: ${codeLine(sum)}
                            \n\n ** Do you want to call another card or do you wanna stay? **`;

                        });
                    }

                    else {

                        matchEmbed.description = `**you pulled ${codeLine(randCard)} from the deck!
                        \n${interaction.user.username}'s cards** \n${codeLine(playerCards.join(" | "))} | sum: ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}
                        \n\n **Dealer's cards **${codeLine(dealerCard1)} | ${codeLine(dealerCard2)} | sum: ${codeLine(sum)}
                        \n\n ** Do you want to call another card or do you wanna stay? **`; 
                    }

                    if (lodash.sum(playerCards) > 21) {

                        matchEmbed.description = `**${interaction.user.username}'s cards** \n${codeLine(playerCards.join(" | "))} | sum: ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}
                        \n **Busted! The sum your cards are over 21!**
                        \n\n **Dealer's cards **${codeLine(dealerCard1)} | ${codeLine(dealerCard2)} | sum: ${codeLine(sum)}
                        \n\n ** Wait for the Dealer... **`;

                        row.components[0].setDisabled(false);
                    }

                    if (lodash.sum(playerCards) == 21) {

                        matchEmbed.description = `**${interaction.user.username}'s cards** \n${codeLine(playerCards.join(" | "))} | sum: ${codeLine(lodash.sum(playerCards))}
                        \n **Blackjack!**
                        \n\n **Dealer's cards **${codeLine(dealerCard1)} | ${codeLine(dealerCard2)} | sum: ${codeLine(sum)}
                        \n\n ** Wait for the Dealer... **`;

                        row.components[0].setDisabled(false);
                    }

                    break;

                case "stay":
                    matchEmbed.setDescription("stay");

                    break;
            }

            btnInt.editReply({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [row] });
        });

        function randomCard() {

            randCard = chance.pickone(cards);

            if (randCard !== 1) {

                cards.splice(cards.indexOf(randCard), 1);
                playerCards.push(randCard);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!